# How to get the InstanceID using the PublicDnsName?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

With the AWS CLI, given a `PublicDnsName`, how can I get the `InstanceID`? I tried

`aws ec2 describe-instances --filters 'Name=publicdnsname,Values=ec2....`

but it complains that

> publicdnsname is not a valid filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `dns-name`

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=dns-name,Values=ec2-xxxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com" --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].InstanceId' --output text
```

Output

```
i-00123458ca3fa2c4f
```

Answer (score 1):

The valid filters are listed [in the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html).

To filter by public DNS name the filter name you should use is: `dns-name`